# How to split a string using a specific delimiter in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have a String variable and I want to extract the three substrings separeted by ; to three string variables.

```
String application_command = "{10,12; 4,5; 2}";
```

I cannot use substring method because this string can be like any of the following or similar patterns also.

```
String application_command = "{10,12,13,9,1; 4,5; 2}"

String application_command = "{7; 1,2,14; 1}"
```

The only thing that is common in these patterns is there are three sections separated by ;.

Any insight is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you need a `split-string-into-string-array` function with a custom separator character.

There are already several sources on the web and at stackoverflow (e.g. [Split String into String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072320/split-string-into-string-array)).

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072320/split-string-into-string-array
String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
  int found = 0;
  int strIndex[] = {0, -1};
  int maxIndex = data.length()-1;

  for(int i=0; i<=maxIndex && found<=index; i++){
    if(data.charAt(i)==separator || i==maxIndex){
        found++;
        strIndex[0] = strIndex[1]+1;
        strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }

  return found>index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```

You can use this function as follows (with ";" as separator):

```
String part01 = getValue(application_command,';',0);
String part02 = getValue(application_command,';',1);
String part03 = getValue(application_command,';',2);
```

EDIT: correct single quotes and add semicolons in the example.

Comment: Yes I saw the previous stackoverflow links. Your solution works with a minor change. String part01 = getValue(application_command , ';' , 0);. I got it working with your solution and this change. Thank you for the support.

Comment: You are right. Single quotes are correct for the second parameter (char) and each line must of course end with a semicolon.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I like it, but I need a little extension for the function. How can I add to the function parameter like start_at_position to look like this:
String getValue(String data, char separator, int startpos, int index) Thank you!

Comment: You can easily implement this by using string.substring(from) function. This could be done by calling the function with a substring (e.g., getValue(yourString.substring(yourStartPost), separator, index);) or by extending the function with an additional parameter (e.g., "data = data.substring (startpos);" in the first line of the function). Further details of substring are available online at the Arduino Reference page: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/substring/

Answer (score 0):

The new SafeString Arduino library (available from the library manager) provides a number of tokenizing/substring methods without the heap fragmentation of the String class

See
 https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ArduinoProgramming/SafeString/index.html

for a detailed tutorial

In this case your can use

```
#include "SafeString.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  createSafeString(appCmd, 50);  // large enought for the largest cmd
  createSafeString(token1, 20);
  createSafeString(token2, 20);
  createSafeString(token3, 20);
  appCmd = "{10,12,13,9,1; 4,5; 2}";
  size_t nextIdx = 1; //step over leading {
  nextIdx = appCmd.stoken(token1, nextIdx, ";}");
  nextIdx++; //step over delimiter
  nextIdx = appCmd.stoken(token2, nextIdx, ";}");
  nextIdx++; //step over delimiter
  nextIdx = appCmd.stoken(token3, nextIdx, ";}");
  nextIdx++; //step over delimiter
  // can trim tokens if needed e.g. token1.trim()
  Serial.println(token1);
  Serial.println(token2); 
  Serial.println(token3);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Also look at [pfodParser](https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/pfodParserLibraries/index.html) which parses these types of messages {  } for use by pfodApp.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not forget to call delete[]** to free the memory after the use of the array, that said here is my solution:

```
String* split(String& v, char delimiter, int& length) {
  length = 1;
  bool found = false;

  // Figure out how many itens the array should have
  for (int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
    if (v[i] == delimiter) {
      length++;
      found = true;
    }
  }

  // If the delimiter is found than create the array
  // and split the String
  if (found) {

    // Create array
    String* valores = new String[length];

    // Split the string into array
    int i = 0;
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < length; itemIndex++) {
      for (; i < v.length(); i++) {

        if (v[i] == delimiter) {
          i++;
          break;
        }
        valores[itemIndex] += v[i];
      }
    }

    // Done, return the values
    return valores;
  }

  // No delimiter found
  return nullptr;
}
```

Here is an example of how to use:

```
void loop() {
  String test = "1,2,3,4,5";
  int qtde;

  String* t = split(test, ',', qtde);

  for (int i = 0; i < qtde; i++) {
    Serial.println(t[i]);
    delay(1000);
  }

  delete[] t;
}
```